# Network availability method throwing exception & crushing the App

Tags: android

I used the below method for checking the network availability but the app is crushing and it's throwing exception.

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager
            .getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

it throws below exception,

```
MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10046 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.
```

But i gave permission in manifest.xml file.

here it is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="hello.app.cri" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
<activity android:name=".MatchAct" >

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Aboutmeh" >

        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Permissions go outside of the `<application>` tags.

Comment: Permissions are always outside the application tag not inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uses-permission tag should be use outside application tag.

try this code :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="hello.app.cri" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >



    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MatchAct" >

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Aboutmeh" >

    </activity>


</application>
```

Hope this help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Your error itself is self explanatory. You have not given the permission properly. Put  tag outside your  tag.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have defined permissions within `<application>` tag.

You have to define permissions outside of `<application>` tag.

E.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="hello.app.cri" >

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

         <!-- Define Permissions Here -->

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MatchAct" />
        <activity android:name=".Aboutmeh" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score -2):

To access internet we need INTERNET Permission
and To detect network status we need ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE Permission at yours

AndroidManifest.xml

make sure you have permissions at menifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="hello.app.cri" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >



    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MatchAct" >

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Aboutmeh" >

    </activity>


</application>
```

and make sure they should be outside of application tag and but inside manifest tag